# Raising the logging level of a function (or class method) in Python

Tags: python, logging

For debugging purposes, I would like to be able to raise the logging level inside a specific function (or class method) without having to edit its definition.  For example, assuming that the global logging level is `INFO`, I would like the logging level of a specific function to be `DEBUG`.

I don't mind if I will have to restart the application. Is this possible?

Comment: Using a decorator first comes to mind.  Risking SO ettiquette take a look at this - [Logging decorator with specified logger (or default)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Logging_decorator_with_specified_logger_.28or_default.29)

Comment: can you show what your original function looks like? does it call `logging.info(...)`? or using a custom logger (i.e. `logger.info(...)`)? if a custom logger, is the logger used in other places in your system?

Comment: [Python Cookbook Chapter 9. Metaprogramming](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch09.html)

Comment: @wwii: Thanks. If you convert your comment to an answer, I will choose it.

Comment: np, I'm pretty sure *Answers* are not supposed just link to non-SO pages and I don't think I could improve on or sufficiently embellish the `Decorator with User Adjustable Attributes` in the Python Cookbook without more specifics in the question - the `attach_wrapper` idea is cool.  Enjoy :).